# extjs 4.1 remote grid sorting, and filtering with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I need to add sorting and filtering to my grid. The grid is part of the tab panel. I can see in the Firebug the following parameters to the call to the controller:

```
_dc 1361741346485
limit   200
page    2
sort    [{"property":"IsLate","direction":"ASC"}]
start   200
```

What parameters do I need to add to the controller method to accept sort parameter from the request?  I guess I would need to serialize it.  I tried to create a sort object with property and direction, but when I debug, the parameter received has property and direction as nulls.  Is there a naming convention I need to follow? I'm confused.
Thank you.

This is my code:
**LateGrid.js**

```
  Ext.define('FICMTB.ui.LateModel', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       fields: [
    { name: 'Id' },      
    { name: 'IsLate' },      
    { name: 'Comments' },  
    { name: 'Description' }],
    idProperty: 'Id'
 });

 Ext.define("FICMTB.ui.LateGrid", {
     extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
     requires: [
        'FICMTB.ui.LateModel',
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
        ],

initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.columns = me.buildColumns();
    me.filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false, // json encode the filter query
        filters: [{
            options: ['YES', 'NO'],
            dataIndex: 'IsLate'
        }]
    };
    me.features = [me.filters];
    me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'FICMTB.ui.LateModel',
        remoteSort: true,
        storeId: 'LateStoreId',
        autoLoad: true,
        buffered: true,
        autoSync: true,

        pageSize: 200,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            timeout: 600000,

            url: '/Late/Transactions/',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'transactions',
                totalProperty: "Total"
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'transactions'
            }
        }
    });

    me.selModel = new Ext.selection.RowModel({
        singleSelect: true
    });

    me.autoSizeColumns = true;

    me.autoScroll = true;
    me.forcefit = true;

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

buildColumns: function () {
    var me = this;

    return [
    { text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'Id', hidden: true, hideable: false },
    { text: 'Is Late' dataIndex: 'IsLate', sortable: true, width: 50, filter:true},      
    { text: 'Comments', dataIndex: 'Comments', width: 250, sortable: true },
    { text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'Description', width: 250, sortable: true }];
  },
  height: 600,
  width: 'auto'
});
```

**LateController.cs**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[ActionName("LateTransactions")]
public ActionResult GetLateTransactions(string page, string start, string limit, xxxxxx sorting, yyyyy filtering)
{
    // what should xxxxx and yyyyy be? how should I name the sorting and filtering parameters?
    //            returns json 
}
```

EDIT:
   I tried to use Sorting object, but it comes as null

```
// Sorting 
// NOT Simple Sort: 
// Request:  index?sort=[{"property":"email","direction":"DESC"}, {"property":"last_name","direction":"ASC"}, ...] 
public class Sorting 
{ 
    public string property { set; get; } 
    public string direction { set; get; } 
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[ActionName("LateTransactions")]
public ActionResult GetLateTransactions(string page, string start, string limit, Sorting sort, yyyyy filtering)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sort I was actually getting a json string.  I had to set encode to true for filters so the filters parameter passed into my controller method is a json string:

```
   me.filters = {
       ftype: 'filters',
       **encode: true, // json encode the filter query**
       filters: [{
           options: ['YES', 'NO'],
           dataIndex: 'IsLate'
       }]
   };
```

I'm using  Newtonsoft library that has DeserializeObject method - it takes a json string and converts it into an object.  So, for filtering, my object is this:

```
   public class Filtering
   {
       public string type { get; set; }
       public string value { get; set; }
       public string field { get; set; }
   }
```

and in my controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [ActionName("LateTransactions")]
    public ActionResult GetLateTransactions(string page, string start, string limit,    Sorting sort, Filtering filter)
    {
    // get all the filters
        List<Filtering> deserzdFilter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Filtering>>(filter);
        ....
//            returns json(model);
     }
```

Comment: In your action parameter for filter, shouldn't that be of type String? You seem to be receiving a Filtering, and then deserializing it into a List<Filtering>.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with MVC3 at all, but what you need to do is:

- Map parameters correctly (you would probably do this by using a string sort parameters for that method) and make sure you get the sort value as a JSON string.
- Then you need to de-serialize the JSON string as an object (I think this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx).

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to map parameters. I tried string, object - I must be doing something wrong.  Either name or object, but I cannot get it to map properly. Once I get that I know how to deal with json.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MVC3 either, however I've used .Net WCF with Extjs with good success.  For example...

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
   public Stream getEvent_list(string TableName, string WhereParams,string page, string start, string limit, string sort)
   {
       string sorting = "date desc";

       if (WhereParams == null) WhereParams = "";
       if (sort != null)
       {
           sorting = getSorting(sort);  // parse the sorting json parameter
       }

blah blah....

       string sql = "select * from mytable order by " + sorting;
        /// return json as streamn

  }

 //  -------------------- getSorting ------------------------------------------------
// Parse the passed sorting JSON object into a string for SQL query.
// for example sort= [{property:'dr'},{order:'desc'},{property:'doi'},{order:'asc'},]
// gets converted to 'dr desc, dor asc' (SQL friendly format).

   private string getSorting(string sort)
   {
       string sorting = "";

       string[] pairs = sort.Split(',');

       for ( int i=0; i< pairs.Length; i +=2 )
       {
           string[] pair = pairs[i].Split(':');
           string[] ord = pairs[i+1].Split(':');

           if (sorting.Length > 0)
           {
               sorting += ",";
           }
           // get rid of all extra json characters.
           sorting += pair[1].Trim(' ', '{', '}', '[', ']', '\\', '\"', '"') + " " + ord[1].Trim(' ', '{', '}', '[', ']', '\\', '\"', '"');
       }

       return sorting;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that sort parameter comes as null.  I guess it must be MVC and I probably need to look at writing a custom binding